# noframenumbering: no page number for specific slides in rmarkdown::beamer_presentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

In a LaTex beamer presentation generated with rmarkdown::beamer_presentation, how can I remove the slide numbers for specific slides?

Since the slides contain plots and tables generated by `R-markdown`, plain `LaTex` approaches like the attempt below likely won't work.

````
``` {=latex}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{Frame name}

Frame without slide number but with Rmd-generated tables and plots.
- All other frames still have slide numbers.

\end{frame}
```
````

Comment: Your question makes no sense without [mre]. The default theme does not even show frame numbers

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz my apologies, I should have provided a simple MWE to also describe more precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `noframenumbering` option is not what you think it is. It is to exclude the frame from being counted.

To remove the footline with the page numbering, you can use the `plain` option:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
    theme: "THEMENAME"
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true 
---

## Slide 1 {.noframenumbering}

test

## Slide 2 {.plain}

test

## Slide 3

test
```

Comment: In fact, `## Slide 1 {.noframenumbering}` – so a slide with the same number as the slide before – was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!